# when I try to build my project using eas build command. it shows the message of "Run gradlew" to see logs but I don't have it so how can I see logs

Tags: react-native, expo, build.gradle

Every dependency and eas-cli is upto date instead of that expo app gives the error of

[stderr]
e: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-splash-screen/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/splashscreen/SplashScreenReactActivityLifecycleListener.kt:16:3 'onContentChanged' overrides nothing
541

> Task :expo-file-system:compileReleaseKotlin
> 542
> w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions
> 543
> 204 actionable tasks: 204 executed
> 544
> [stderr]
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 545
> [stderr]

- What went wrong:
  546
  [stderr]
  Execution failed for task ':expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseKotlin'.
  547
  [stderr]

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> 548
> [stderr]
> Compilation error. See log for more details
> 549
> [stderr]

- Try:
  550
  [stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> 551
> [stderr]
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> 552
> [stderr]
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> 553
> [stderr]

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  554
  [stderr]
  BUILD FAILED in 5m 40s
  555
  Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

I tried to update all dependency but it did not work.